# JAX-RS application class executing twice

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am writing REST application using Jersey. Instead of web.xml, I am using JAX-RS application.

```
@ApplicationPath("/services") 
public class RestApp extends Application {
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
     System.out.println("Working Directory restapp= " +
              System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    classes.add(SchemaValidator.class);
    return classes;
}
```

}

Here, the message "Working directory = " is printed twice. The method gets hit twice while debugging. That is getClasses() is being executed twice. Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: I don't know if usage of the `getClasses()` method is specified, but I'd say that it could be used as many times as needed by the JAX-RS container.

What would matter most, is if the constructor of this class is called multiple times maybe.

Comment: My best guess would be that it's just a side effect of the implementation. I'm sure the implementors assumed that it should not be a problem as you aren't actually initializing anything. I wouldn't be concerned. I would be more concerned if the `getSingletons` was called more than one, as that's where you'd be doing initialization.

Comment: I haven't used `getSingletons`. When I printed stack trace in the class `RestApp` I get following two, (those who invoked `RestApp`) 

1- com.mt.usw.tls.ei.rest.RestApp.getClasses(RestApp.java:23)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:1124)
 
2 - com.mt.usw.tls.ei.rest.RestApp.getClasses(RestApp.java:23)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig$3.run(ResourceConfig.java:1210) Is this right?